# Use answer from more than 1 HTML drop downs to choose link

Tags: html

I want to write a simple HTML page containing only two drop-down lists and a submit button. After hitting the submit button I want to load a new page depended on both selects.

Here's a simple example of how the page should look like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <select required name="Product">
        <option>-Select Product-</option>
        <option value="pA">ProductA</option>
        <option value="pB">ProductB</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <select required name="Action">
        <option>-Select Action-</option>
        <option value="actionA">ActionA</option>
        <option value="actionB">ActionB</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit"/>
</body>
```

I know that I could make a drop-down containing the four combinations(pAactionA,pBactionA,pAactionB,pBactionB) or even split it into more pages(one with the product selection and two with the respective action selections) but the actual drop-downs contain a few more options.

I have named the files corresponding to the pages as pBactionA.php and I am guessing I need something like

```
<form  action="selectAselectB.php" method="post">
```

where selectAselectB is the concatanation of the selected values.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ... just use a form? What's wrong? Where are you stuck at?

Comment: I'm pretty new to html but so far every time I have used a form "actions" contains a specific php file.

Comment: Google "html forms" gives a lot of results. Where are you stuck at? Show your code using a `form`.

Comment: I say "form" as an example. To my knowledge, an action in form is statically defined whereas I'm looking for something that changes dynamically(If I can use the terms "statically" and "dynamically" in this case-not sure)

Comment: I see that using `form` is the most suitable here. It can do exactly what you want in this case. Just do it. If you succeed, you can post an answer to your own question.

Comment: Well, I guess I can try but how are you suggesting to take the select values?(To replace the "selectAselectB" in the code)

Comment: The server must handle that.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to leverage the power of  query parameters. So you have one page that you always get directed to but the page loads differently depending on what the parameters are. You know how you load a page and sometimes the address bare looks like this: google.com?watch=blahblah. You need to do that. Use JavaScript to parse through the url you want to go through and conditionally display data based on what comes after the ?. If you are using a back end language like php it becomes bunch easier to grab those parameters. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am afraid I don't know javascript but I do know php(just the basics though). Could you please explain your suggestion in more detail? Thanks

Comment: In php you can use $_POST and $_GET. These are global variables available at every scope. What you want to do is set the $_POST variable when you send the data via your html form. What will happen is every name attribute in your html will will be the key and the value of that element will be the value in the $_POST variable. So what you will have something like $_POST['answer1'] and $_POST['answer2']. You need to send these variables to some backend file you name something like processing.php. From there figure out which if the 4 display types you want. Then redirect to one page like ...

Comment: results.php?resulttype=4. Then in your html you will use php to display data like: 

    <p>You selected<?php echo $_GET['resulttype']  ?></p>

This way you will always have a different result based on what you get from your backed processing file.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are talking about an intermediate page before going ,let's say, to pAactionB? Or did I misunderstood completely?

Comment: That is correct. Send the two answers to a page in between your starting and ending page. That page will give you one of 4 values back. Send that value to the end page and display that page based on what you value you get using $_GET. Remember $_GET gets is values from the url. Each value in the army is separated by the & symbol. google.com?var1=54&var2=34